# Eclipse on Mac won't let me select files

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to import jar files into eclipse but, every time I try to, it always shows up grayed out, and can't select anything but the file extension. Any thoughts?

[image: screenshot of what I am seeing]

Comment: @MrFisherman I'll look into that. I'm just using Eclipse because that's what our Prof. uses here at uni. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFisherman Comments from [IntelliJ fanboys](https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/621203966634917888) are not welcome. Please respect the rules of Stack Overflow. Be aware that all Java developers know that there are more than one Java IDE. For my needs, IJ would not work and I would miss the incremental compiler.

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this? Older versions of Eclipse have issues on macOs 11. The current 2021-09 works fine, and has no problems with that dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 According to the views/editors close button I would guess it is Eclipse 2021-09. Does in preferences _Java > Build Path > User Libraries_ the _Add External JARs..._ button work for you?

Comment: Yes, the dialog is fine. It is normal for parts of the file list to be grayed but the rest of the dialog is OK. I'm on the current macOS 11.6

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my issue.

I went ahead and upgraded my MacOS to Big Sur 11.6 and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. All you need to do is unzip the file. You can import the unzipped version of the file into eclipse.